# Missing end portal. It's impossible to beat my Minecraft world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My end portal (in Minecraft) is no where to be found. The current version is 1.94 and the seed is 1990018518. When I try to use an eye of ender to locate the portal the strong hold is empty and I can't get the eyes of ender to locate a different portal. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What exactly does it mean "the strong hold is empty"?

Answer (score 4):

128 strongholds generate in every world. The eye of ender always leads you to the closest one, so you can go very far away and try again from there.